# Filling height of page with position absolute

Tags: html, css, reactjs

How would I position a div to take up 100% of the page height even when the page has a scroll bar and I scroll to the bottom. My div is a modal and is positioned under a navbar, I set the min-height to 100vh, but it doesn't seem to expand to the bottom of the page when I scroll down. I'm using position absolute not fixed because, I want it to be relative to the navbar.

```
    <header className ={styles.header}>
    <span className={styles.header__item} onClick={() => handleTab(1)}>Library</span>
    <div className={styles.img} onClick={()=>handleOptions()}>                   
    </div>  
    <input className={styles.search} type ="text" placeholder="Search"></input> 
    <PlayerModal open={playerOpen}/>
    </header> 


.modalStyles{
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 26vw;
    position: absolute;
    left: 74%;
    top: 100%;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}
```

Comment: `100vh` means 100% of the view height, i.e. the overall visible portion of all of your page (could be the window on desktop of the full screen on mobile)

Answer (score 0):

you can use position sticky instead of absolute and set top of this At the bottom of the nav.

```css
#sticky {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  background: #f83d23;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 70px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px #000;
  color: #fff;
}
.extra,
#wrapper {
  width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
#wrapper {
  height: 800px;
}
.extra {
  height: 100px;
}
body {
  font-family: georgia;
  height: 1000px;
}
h4 {
  text-align: center;
}
@media (min-height: 768px) {
  #wrapper{
    height: 2000px;
  }
}
```

```html
<h4>Scroll to see the sticky element <em>sticking</em></h4>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="sticky">
    sticky
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="extra"></div>
```